# What Causes SDL_Renderer to be invalid?

Tags: c++, textures, sdl, render, sdl-2

I'm trying to make a 2D game where the background is a hockey rink. The error handler said the Render-er didn't initialize thus making the texture not initialize. I know the BMP loads because I don't get an error for that. Don't worry about the camera stuff. The background is supposed to scroll. I just need the background to render. The code may not be the best, but corrections are always appreciated.

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int fps = 60;

SDL_Window *window;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    SDL_Surface  *screen;
    SDL_Surface *background = SDL_LoadBMP("hockeyrink.bmp");
    if(background == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Background init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
    }
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if(renderer == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Renderer init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
    }
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,background);
    if(texture == NULL)
    {
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(0, "Texture init error", SDL_GetError(), window);
    }

    const int speed = 5;
    SDL_Rect camera;
    camera.x = 0;
    camera.y = 0;
    camera.w = 800;
    camera.h = 600;
    bool b[2] = {0,0};
    Uint32 start;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("", 300, 100, 1024, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << ("could not create window: %s/n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        start = SDL_GetTicks();
        SDL_Event event;

        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = false;
                SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
                SDL_FreeSurface(background);
                SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
                SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
                SDL_Quit();
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    b[0]=1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    b[1]=1;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
                switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    b[0]=0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    b[1]=0;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if(b[0])
        {
            x+=speed;
            camera.y+=speed;
            if (camera.y > 3000-800)
            {
                camera.y=0;
            }

        }
        else if(b[1])
        {
            x-=speed;
            camera.y-=speed;

            if (camera.y <= 0)
            {
                camera.y = 2000-800;
            }


            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }
        if(1000/fps>SDL_GetTicks()-start)
        {
            SDL_Delay(1000/fps-(SDL_GetTicks() - start));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the exact output from SDL_GetError (or from the program in general)?

Comment: It just says "Invalid".

Comment: I believe you need to create your window before passing it to create the renderer.

Comment: I highly recomend splitting your code into different functions. One for initializing, one for loading assets, one for game loop, one for input handling, etc...  As it stands, your code is messy and does things all over the place. Load your assets after initializing everything ( window, renderer, ... )

Comment: Also, the background doesn't actually render. The window is just blank. Does anyone have a fix for that. There's got to be something in my code that's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create renderer, the window pointer does not point to anything(i.e. it is uninitialized).
You must create the window **before**  creating the renderer.
So put the lines:

```
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("", 300, 100, 1024, 800, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        cout << ("could not create window: %s/n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
```

before the line: `SDL_Renderer *renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);`